# Is performance gained when using continue in a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, performance, dictionary

continue first? or Should the code just go ahead?

Example:

```
for (int a : array) {
    if (map.containsKey(a))
        continue;
    ~~~
}

//or

for (int a : array) {
    if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
        ~~~
    }
}
```

Which phrase is faster? Or is there no difference in performance? Then what's the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can also add labels to the `continue` statement. In fact, `continue` is actually a syntactic sugar for a `goto LABEL` statement with `LABEL` pointing to the top of the most inner loop.

```
for (int a : array) {
    if (map.containsKey(a))
        continue;
    // ... 
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
label1:
for (int a : array) {
    if (map.containsKey(a))
        continue label1;
    // ... 
}
```

When compiled, both produce the same bytecode. Actually, when decompiling their respective `.class` file of either one, you'll see the decompiler converting them into your second version:

```
for (int a : array) {
    if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
        // ...
    }
```

Besides the readability reason mentioned that you get your code one nested level less, there is no noticeable performance difference between the 2.

The presence of the `continue` statement in the language syntax is not even necessary. Most probably, it remained for backward compatibility reasons. By contrast, the Scala language doesn't offer a `continue` statement in the standard library, simply because there is nothing that `continue` offers that you can't do with a Boolean value that changes when some condition is not met anymore.

Here's how `javap` disassembles your examples. I added a `println` statement instead of `~~~`:

Using `continue`:

```
74: iload         5
76: iload         4
78: if_icmpge     118
81: aload_3
82: iload         5
84: iaload
85: istore        6
87: aload_1
88: iload         6
90: invokestatic  #10         // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
93: invokeinterface #22,  2   // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
98: ifeq          104
101: goto          112
104: getstatic     #26         // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
107: iload         6
109: invokevirtual #32         // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
112: iinc          5, 1
115: goto          74
```

Without using `continue`:

```
  74: iload         5
  76: iload         4
  78: if_icmpge     115
  81: aload_3
  82: iload         5
  84: iaload
  85: istore        6
  87: aload_1
  88: iload         6
  90: invokestatic  #10         // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
  93: invokeinterface #22,  2   // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.containsKey:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  98: ifne          109
 101: getstatic     #26         // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 104: iload         6
 106: invokevirtual #32         // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
 109: iinc          5, 1
 112: goto          74
```

They look almost identical. Notice in the first version, using `continue` translates into a `goto` statement.

Answer (score 3):

They are entirely indistinguishable. Java, like many languages, compiles to bytecode, JVM bytecode in this case. And at the bytecode level, things like `if` statements don't exist. They get compiled down to conditional and unconditional jumps to labels. Your first code block will compile to a conditional jump back to the top of the loop. Something like

```
// Pseudocode
loop:
  _cond = map.containsKey(a)
  jump_if_true loop, _cond
  ...
end:
  jump loop
```

Your second will compile to something like

```
// Pseudocode
loop:
  _cond = map.containsKey(a)
  jump_if_false end, _cond
  ...
end:
  jump loop
```

And since `end` is an unconditional jump to `loop`, any good optimizer will turn this, immediately, into the former.

Just to be sure, I took the two functions you proposed above (replacing `~~~` with a `System.out.println`) and compiled them. They produce, verbatim, the same bytecode. After decompiling back to Java, they look entirely identical.

So don't micro-optimize. Write your code, and trust the compiler to handle things within its control. "Should I use `continue` or `if` here" is a micro-optimization. "Can I turn this triple nested loop into fewer iterations" is probably a good thing to ask up-front.